# SQLDataSource update contains null when it should not

Tags: asp.net

Please have a look at the code below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHistoricNames" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID = "SQLHistoricNames" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="id">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="idHyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id", "frmidHistoricNames.aspx?id={0}") %>' Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:HyperLink>                          
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastUpdated">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LastUpdatedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastUpdated") %>'></asp:Label>                           
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastChecked">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LastCheckedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastChecked") %>'></asp:Label>                           
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Usercode">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsercode" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Usercode") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>       
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateHistoricName" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLidHistoricNames" runat="server" UpdateCommand="update dbaperson set Usercode=@Usercode WHERE ID=@ID">
            <SelectParameters>

              <asp:Parameter Name="Usercode" Type="String" />
           </SelectParameters>
           <UpdateParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Usercode" Type="String" />

              </UpdateParameters>
```

The parameter for @Usercode is always null when the update statement runs.  The parameter for @ID is not.  Why is the parameter value for @Usercode null? I am not sure how to trouble shoot this (I would usually step through code but this is all declared declaratively).

Comment: Don't you also need the `<asp:Parameter Name="Usercode" Type="String" />` element to occur under `<UpdateParameters>` too? Also note that the default behaviour for empty strings is to convert them to `NULL` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.convertemptystringtonull.aspx

Comment: @Dash, I have updated the question.  The update parameter is there.

Comment: You don't appear to have any items in your `DropDownList`.

Comment: @Richard Deeming, the drop down list is created in the code behind.